# How can I have a Print Method, Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to my webpage to have a print button, Like this.

```
<button>Print</button>
```

then when you click the print button. they will pop up a print properties,

Thanks for helping.

Comment: add onclick="print()"

Comment: alert(window.print===print) proves they are the exact same thing, some people just like using globals...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as simple as:

```
<button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
```

Comment: **Alan** Can you Do a whole Code for javascript.. for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by a whole code? window.print() is a JavaScript call, and that's all you need. You could implement a function that called window.print(), but it would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick. Using JavaScript's print method:

```
 <button onclick='window.print();'>Print</button>
```

Comment: There is no document.print(), you should use window.print()

Comment: There is no `document.print`, at least in Firefox. The `window.print` that is there now is correct.

Comment: why does everyone use "window.print()" but just "alert(123)" (no window) ?

Comment: @dandavis Were I going to use `alert`, I would import it into my IFEE via `var alert = window.alert;` first, or use `window.alert`.

Comment: **DaveE** Can you Do a whole Code for javascript.. for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @dandavis In my case I always use window when I am referring to a global var or function. It let me identify easy when I am accessing to global scope and also prevent future errors.

Comment: @janmichaelmallari there is no more code. The print function "comes with the browser".

Comment: the other one is with people using getComputedStyle, they always say "document.defaultView.getComputedStyle" for some reason. yet, never d=new window.Date()...